# How to monitor the Pacemaker cluster using a script?

Tags: rhel, cluster, pacemaker

I have created a two node cluster (both nodes RHEL 7) using `pacemaker`. It is used to run a custom application. I have created below resources and assigned it to the cluster:

1. A shared storage for application data
2. A virtual IP

It works perfectly fine.

Now, we have a requirement. Currently the failover happens only if something goes wrong with the entire server. Pacemaker is unaware of the status of the application running on the active node and completely ignores it. We have a shell script that is able to run a health check on the application and returns true/false values based on the health of the application.
Can anyone please suggest me how to configure pacemaker to use this shell script to regularly check status of the application on the active node of the cluster and initiate failover if script returns a false value.

I have seen examples, in webserver clusters people create a sample html page and use this (`http://127.0.0.1/samplepage.html`) as a resource with pacemaker to check the health of apache webserver in active node.

Please guide me how to achieve similar result using a shell script.

**Update:**

Here is my configuration:

```
[root@node1 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: webspheremq
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node1 (version 1.1.15-11.el7-e174ec8) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Jun 14 20:38:48 2017          Last change: Tue Jun 13 20:04:58 2017 by root via crm_attribute on svdg-stg29

2 nodes and 3 resources configured: 2 resources DISABLED and 0 BLOCKED from being started due to failures

Online: [ node1 node2 ]

Full list of resources:

 Resource Group: websphere
     websphere_fs       (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node1
     websphere_vip      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started node1
     FailOverScript     (ocf::heartbeat:Dummy): Started node1


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

To start and stop the application, I have two shell scripts. During failover, I would need `stop.sh` to run in the node from which resources will be moved and `start.sh` to run in the node to which cluster is failing over.

I did little experiment and found that people are using dummy resource to achieve this kind of requirements (to execute scripts during failover).

So here is what I have done so far:

I created a dummy resource (`FailOverScript`) for testing application start/stop scripts like below:

```
[root@node1 tmp]# pcs status resources
 Resource Group: websphere
     websphere_fs       (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node1
     websphere_vip      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started node1
     **FailOverScript     (ocf::heartbeat:Dummy): Started node1**
```

As of now, I included test scripts under start and stop actions of the resource FailOverScript. It should execute scripts failoverstartscript.sh and failoverstopscript.sh respectively when this dummy resource starts and stops.

```
[root@node1 heartbeat]# pwd
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat
[root@node1  heartbeat]#
[root@node1  heartbeat]# grep -A5 "start()" FailOverScript
FailOverScript_start() {
    FailOverScript_monitor
    /usr/local/bin/failoverstartscript.sh
    if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then
        return $OCF_SUCCESS
    fi
[root@node1  heartbeat]#
[root@node1  heartbeat]#
[root@node1  heartbeat]# grep -A5 "stop()" FailOverScript
FailOverScript_stop() {
    FailOverScript_monitor
    /usr/local/bin/failoverstopscript.sh
    if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then
        rm ${OCF_RESKEY_state}
    fi
```

But when this dummy resource is started/stopped (through manual failover), the script does not execute. Tried different things but I am still unable to figure out the reason for this.
Need some help to find the reason for the scripts not to execute automatically during failover.

Comment: Can you share your configuration?

Comment: ... and how you're starting your application? Ideally, you would configure your application in Pacemaker, which would allow Pacemaker to monitor the application AND the node.

Comment: @MattKereczman  I have added configuration details as update.

Comment: That's just the view of the running resources, I want to see how they're configured: `# pcs cluster cib > /tmp/cib.xml`

Comment: Please find the requested file here: http://ge.tt/28wrZIl2

Comment: pasted here as well, I'll look in a little bit: https://pastebin.com/FgmNEBKz

Comment: @Vinod You added the stubs for the `start` and `stop` functions of your `FailOverScript`, but what about the `monitor` function? It sounds like you want your `monitor` function to call the script that will give you status.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to modify the Dummy RA to execute arbitrary scripts, you could instead look at using the `anything` resource-agent.

```
# pcs resource describe ocf:heartbeat:anything
ocf:heartbeat:anything - Manages an arbitrary service

This is a generic OCF RA to manage almost anything.

Resource options:
  binfile (required): The full name of the binary to be executed.
                      This is expected to keep running with the
                      same pid and not just do something and
                      exit.
  cmdline_options: Command line options to pass to the binary
  workdir: The path from where the binfile will be executed.
  pidfile: File to read/write the PID from/to.
  logfile: File to write STDOUT to
  errlogfile: File to write STDERR to
  user: User to run the command as
  monitor_hook: Command to run in monitor operation
  stop_timeout: In the stop operation: Seconds to wait for kill
                -TERM to succeed before sending kill -SIGKILL.
                Defaults to 2/3 of the stop operation timeout.
```

You would point the `anything` agent at your script as the `binfile=` parameter, then, if you have some way of monitoring your custom application other than checking for a running pid (that's what the `anything` agent does by default), you can define that in the `monitor_hook` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Kereczman . Sorry, I could not work on this till now. Will check this and update the outcome. Before that one query please. It looks like `anything` RA is missing in my setup. This is what I found in Redhat site [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2840731) .

Comment: I wasn't aware they did that. I agree it's better to write a proper RA, but I'm not sure if I agree that using the 'systemd' unit file is any better or worse than the `anything` agent. The implied assumption that anyone can sit down and write an RA is a little far fetched; to be fair RHEL is geared towards enterprise, so for their audience, that likely isn't an issue. However, if you're still interested in the agent, you can get it from upstream: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/blob/master/heartbeat/anything